# Find all automorphisms of $\wp(2)$ Note that here $2=\{0,1\}$ and $\wp$ is set of subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find all automorphisms of $\wp(2)$ Note that here $2=\{0,1\}$ and $\wp$ is set of subsets.

My idea: Note that $\wp(2)=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$. Let $\Phi :\wp(2)\rightarrow \wp(2)$ be automorphism. **Now, how can I find automorphisms?**

Comment: By an automorphism you mean a bijection?

Comment: Quick tip: to get a $\{$ in Mathjax, use `\{` and `\}`

Comment: $\wp$ is normally reserved for the Weierstrass elliptic function. $\mathcal{P}$ (`\mathcal{P}`) is conventional for power sets.

Comment: Thanks for typos but will you help for my question?

Comment: If you mean bijections, then there are $4! = 24$ of them, so I think it's a bit useless to list them ...

Comment: @Max I mean that automorphism is an isomorphism from a mathematical object to itself

Comment: @Max Can you explain that how did you find this? Obviously, identity is automorphism of $\wp(2)$.

Comment: In general, there are $n!$ bijections from a set of $n$ elements to itself, it's a standard combinatorics result. You can try and prove it by induction

Comment: "Automorphism" implies some structure is to be preserved. ***WHAT*** is the structure that you intend to preserve under these automorphisms?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, you are right.How should the structure be?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Let $(X,<)$ be a structure where $X$ is a set and < is ordered such that for all $x\in X$, $x_1<x_2 \Leftrightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I assumed $X=\wp(2)$.

Comment: @Max Can you say the list of automorphism?

Comment: @Kahler: if you mean bijections then no, because there are $24$ of them. However, if, as indicated in the previous comments,you want those bijections to preserve some ordering then it changes everything

Comment: @Max Yes, I mean bijections. Then, you said that 'no'. Why?

Comment: @Max Since there is no bijection from $(\wp(2),<)$ to $(\wp(2),<)$, we cannot say Aut$(\wp(2))$, can we?

Comment: @Kahler : there are, but there are too many and I don't want to list $24$ bijections